# returnUrl not passed to LogOn action method in AccountController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC application created from the Internet template to use forms authentication, when the user has logged on I want to direct them, say, to the Home|About page.

The LogOn method is that created by the project template, without modification;

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           // etc, etc
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

I've set the defaultUrl in Web.config as follows;

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/Home/About"/>
</authentication>
```

However, when HomeController.LogOn is called the returnUrl parameter is always null. Note the HttpPost attribute on the LogOn method, so the url cannot be passed in the query string.

How can I configure a return url so it gets passed to the LogOn action method and the user is directed to the url's location after log on?

Comment: did you tried return RedirectToAction("Logon"); ?

Comment: Most probably you forgot to post your reurnUrl string in Logon view ? For this purpose, you may use @Html.HiddenFor() helper as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to change the default route in the Global.asax to point to `/Home/About` instead of `/Home/Index`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "About", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Comment: The other thing I can do is redirect to a particular page with a RedirectToAction from within the Login method, once I've checked the credentials. What's bugging me though is that I can't get some value passed to the returnUrl argument of the Login action if it's set as [HttpPost] - is there ant way of doing this.

Comment: I think I might know what you mean, but not quite sure... can you elaborate? I don't want to lead you in the wrong direction just because I'm not clear

Comment: I think bottom line is, if all you want to do is navigate user to Home/About then use the RedirectToAction or change default route - path of least resistance. Unless you are looking for more than just that redirect

Comment: Just frustrating that I can't get anything to pass into the returnUrl argument of the Login method. I can work round it but it's frustrating nevertheless.

Comment: It's used by query string from what I understand. If a user tries to navigate to `/Home/SomeAction/` and `SomeAction` is decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute and isn't logged in, the user is redirected to the logon page. The return Url is then part of the Url in the address bar, once logged in the returnUrl is evaluated and then redirected to the original action. Have a look at the Url when doing that.